# Combining LTRIM and RTIM and REPLACE functions in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, replace, trim

I have a field in a table that has both leading and trailing characters that I would like to remove.

This Statement

***SELECT        FullName AS Category
FROM            dbo.inventory***

produces this result in a table (partial result shown):

- Parts - Belts:Z.360J8
- Parts - Belts:Z.360J14
- Parts - Belts:Z.36355-123
- Parts - Plastics & Frame:Z.103196-001
- Parts - Electrical Cables/Cords:Z.P037153674

I would like to remove the before the dash which would remove "Parts - " and everything trailing the colon ':' so I can be left with only the category and get a table like this:

- Belts
- Belts
- Belts
- Plastics & Frame
- Electrical Cables/Cords

I have tried this and successfully removed the preceding "Parts -" but successfully combine the statement with removing everything after the colon ":"

***SELECT        LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(FullName, 'Parts -', ''))) AS Category
FROM            dbo.inventory***

Produces this result:

- Belts:Z.360J8
- Belts:Z.360J14
- Belts:Z.36355-123
- Plastics & Frame:Z.103196-001
- Electrical Cables/Cords:Z.P037153674

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method using LEFT & CHARINDEX:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(FullName, CHARINDEX(':', FullName) - 1), 'Parts - ', '')
```

CHARINDEX finds the index number of the colon character in the full string, -1 is included to remove it too. LEFT then truncates the string to that position. The REPLACE functions as it does in your original example, removing the 'Parts -
 ' portion (note I've included the space following the hyphen).

LTRIM and RTRIM only remove leading/trailing spaces respectively, so they won't be useful here.

Code to handle rows containing no colon (will return a blank string):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(Fullname, CHARINDEX(':', Fullname)), 'Parts - ', ''), ':', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the statement produced this error: 

Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. 

When I removed the "-1" the statement executes without error but the colon is included. 

SELECT        REPLACE(LEFT(FullName, CHARINDEX(':', FullName)), 'Parts - ', '') AS Category

- Belts:
- Belts:
- Belts:
- Plastics & Frame:
- Electrical Cables/Cords:

Comment: If there's any rows with no colon you will get that error (effectively, position = -1). Removing the -1 allows you to avoid the error but will likely return a blank string for those rows with no colon. If you can find those rows, post examples & how you'd like them handled we can adapt the code accordingly. In the meantime this could work as a non-error workaround: SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(Fullname, CHARINDEX(':', Fullname)), 'Parts - ', ''), ':', '')

Comment: I combined two replace statements to achieve the result, you led me to a solution thank you. 

REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT (FullName, CHARINDEX(':', FullName)), 'Parts - ', ''), ':', '')